# How do I determine audio capabilities on Android?

Tags: android, audio

I'm experimenting with Android's audio recording and playback. Is there a way to enumerate the available audio parameters on my device?

Right now, when I pass a combination of parameters that the hardware (or emulator) doesn't like, I just get an error. So I am having to "guess":

```
int bufferSize; 
int sampleRate;

// does the audio hardware do 44 kHz? 
sampleRate = 44100;
bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, 
    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

if (bufferSize != AudioTrack.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
    // Nope, how about 22 kHz? 
    sampleRate = 22050;
}

bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, 
    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

if (bufferSize != AudioTrack.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) { 
    ...
```

Surely there's a better way!

---

[This chart](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core) indicates that the *only* supported audio input sampling rate is 8 kHz? Is that correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you already looked at [AudioTrack.getNativeOutputSampleRate(int streamType)](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#getNativeOutputSampleRate%28int%29)?

Comment: Hi Marc - yes, I've seen that and it's one piece of the puzzle, but I'm hoping for something more comprehensive (and includes input settings too).

Comment: Bummer. Seems like looping through the possible parameters might be the only way possible currently. See http://bit.ly/c3BieY for another developer's work on this. I agree this is not very optimal, a getCapabilities() function would be nice to have.